# What is $a\times 10^{15}+ b\times 10^{16}$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I cam across this question in an entrance exam, for UK 6th Form? My answer was $a.b*10^{16}$? but I'm  very unsure. Symbolab didn't do me any favours in explaining either. Thanks

Comment: I don't think there's much you can do to simplify that expression.  You can factor out a common $10^{15}$, getting $10^{15}\times (a+10b)$ if that looks simpler to you.

Comment: $a.b$ is not $a+\frac b{10}$ unless you know they are single digits and say something to that effect.  Some people here use the period for multiplication.  It really does not have any meaning at all.  The sum is equal to $(a+\frac b{10})\cdot 10^{16}$ as you were thinking but I don't find that simpler than what you started with.

Comment: @lulu agreed personally I would have left it as it but they are somehow offering 3 marks for it to be simplified. Anyways thanks alot for the help and support

Comment: @RossMillikan i see... would you have left it as (a+ (b/10))*16 or as 10^15×(a+10b)? Unfortunatley since it's a specimen paper it has no mark scheme but 3 marks are offered for it, they've left me confused.

Comment: It would depend on the problem.  Simplification is often in the eye of the beholder.  $(a+10b)10^{15}$ is nice because it shows how much more important $b$ is than $a$.  I would usually leave it as you got it.  I don't think there is a clear answer.  I think the one I gave is better than $(b +\frac a{10})^{16}$ (note my previous comment had $a$ and $b$ backwards in this form).  In your answer, too, it would have to be $b.a\cdot 10^{16}$

Comment: @RossMillikan ah yes, I see the 'backwards' unknowns now...my bad. Thanks for the help though, appreciated

Answer (score 2):

The only simplification is to factor $10^{15}$ and get $$10^{15}(a+10b)$$

Answer (score 0):

Since $10^{16}=10\times 10^{15}$, we can factor out a $10^{15}$ term to obtain

$$a\times 10^{15}+b\times 10^{16}=a\times 10^{15}+10\times b\times 10^{15}=10^{15}\times (a+10\times b)$$

To give a concrete example for the use of that simplification, suppose we have

- $a=2.15$
- $b=0.156$

then

$$2.15\times 10^{15}+0.156\times 10^{16}=10^{15}\times (2.15+10\times .156)=3.71\times 10^{15}$$